# how to set a cancellable timeout in android

Tags: android, timer, timeout, 3g

In my application i want to set a timeout when the user turn on 3G... after a certain amount of time elapsed , i will turn off 3G..
 my problem is cancelling the scheduled timer.. every time i call timer.cancel() .. the program throws errors

the problem cause when i call clearTimeout() method..

```
Timer timer;

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
           public void run() {
               //do something when time's up 
                log("timer","running the timertask..");//my custom log method
                timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
            }

}

public void setTimeout(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);

}

public void clearTimeout(){
    log("timer", "cancelling the timer task");//my custom log method
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
}
```

please help me .. i am an android beginner..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android has a class [CountdownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) which has `start()` and `cancel()`.

Comment: i have tried CountdownTimer but cancel() is not working for me.. when the timer started .. i cannot cancel the sechdule task.. i am using the timer within a service..